# Check if a value exists in a return query in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

I'm new in postgresql. I have made a trigger that is enabled after an insert in a table . My table has among it's values , 1 date value for a start_date and 1 date value for an end_date. When I insert a new row in the table i want to check if there is overlapping with any of the existing dates. So my trigger is the following :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_new() 
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$ 
BEGIN
    if ( 't' = any (select ((NEW.start_date, NEW.end_date) overlaps (start_date, end_date)) from "mytable") ) then 
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'Invalid insertion!';
    else 
        return NEW;
    end if;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

It seems correct to me but when i try to insert a new row in my table i get every time the exception. I can not understand why that happens.. Any thoughts ? Thanks in advance..

Here is the create trigger code :

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_insert 
AFTER INSERT ON "mytable"
FOR EACH ROW 
WHEN (NEW.status = 'current')
EXECUTE PROCEDURE insert_new();
```

Comment: I don't know if it'll help, that's just fast notice. Check if it'll help: ``if  't' = any (select ((NEW.start_date, NEW.end_date) overlaps (start_date, end_date)) from "mytable")  then``

Comment: That bracket looks a bit suspiciously, but I really don't know.

Comment: @Sylogista I tried without the bracket but I get the same result ..

Comment: Show us your trigger definition  on table (CREATE TRIGGER code)

Comment: @OtoShavadze Okay I've added it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_insert 
BEFORE INSERT ON "mytable"
FOR EACH ROW 
WHEN (NEW.status = 'current')
EXECUTE PROCEDURE insert_new();
```

You have `AFTER` INSERT check, drop trigger, then create with with `BEFORE` instead of `AFTER` and try inserts again